# Ubuntu 18.04, standard Ubuntu Dock, multiple action syntax in .desktop file

Tags: .desktop, ubuntu-dock

I'm porting across from previous Ubuntu and want my multiple action Terminal launcher.  I can't see what's wrong with this .desktop file (edited to be simpler than required):

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
#
# this file lives in ~/.local/share/applications
#
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Remote Servers SSH
Comment=Login to my servers by SSH
Exec=gnome-terminal
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=utilities-terminal
Actions=Local;Athena;

[Desktop Action Local]
Name=SSH into localhost
Exec=gnome-terminal

[Desktop Action Athena]
Name=SSH into athena from home
Exec=gnome-terminal --disable-factory --sm-client-disable  --class=remoteserver -x ssh -t xbmc@athena
```

The launcher that appears in the Dock offers only the standard "New Terminal" rather than the actions I've defined. Also, the comment that appears when I hover says "Terminal" when I might have expected "Remote Servers SSH". I think it's just adding the default terminal rather than my details?

When I click on Activities and search for "Remote Servers" it runs, but - if I hover over the launcher it says "Terminal" (doesn't worry me but doesn't sound right) but right click only gives me "New Terminal" between "All Windows" and "Add to Favourites" when I'd expect "SSH into localhost" and "SSH into athena from home".

Comment: The launcher that appears in the Dock offers only the standard "New Terminal" rather than the actions I've defined.  Also, the comment that appears when I hover says "Terminal" when I might have expected "Remote Servers SSH".  I think it's just adding the default terminal rather than my details?

Comment: yes it does, but it's like it's a bog standard terminal.  Hover over the launcher and it says "Terminal" (doesn't worry me but doesn't sound right) but right click only gives me "New Terminal" between "All Windows" and "Add to Favourites" when I'd expect "SSH into localhost" and "SSH into athena from home"

Comment: Probably that's the old default terminal launcher added to the dock previously. Click on "Activities", search for "Remote Servers SSH", right click on the "Remote Servers SSH" launcher and "Add to favourites". (TBH I cannot reproduce: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ISZT.png, although I used different Execs.)

Comment: Got it - thanks! I've edited the answer in above.

Answer (score 2):

The .desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications had to be named "org.gnome.Terminal.desktop" instead of "gnome-terminal.desktop". Otherwise there were two icons for the gnome-terminal in the dock.

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] Okay I had to go "Activities" search for my "Remote Servers..." and then right click -> Add to Favourites from the "Activities" view, rather than having it appear on the dock - by that time it is just the standard terminal...

Comment: Have you managed to find out how to enable Dock icons to show custom .desktop Actions for custom .desktop launchers?