# Actions (from .desktop) are missing for gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, .desktop

I set up gnome-terminal actions in gnome-terminal.desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications/ folder. Basically, I set up preconfigured commands to connect some server with ssh. This was working fine and those actions were listed when I right clicked on the icons at the dock in Unity (16.04). After upgrade I can't see them anymore. They are still configured in gnome-terminal.desktop

Here are relevant lines:
https://pastebin.com/JVF98yRR

Also I am seeing this in the syslog:
failed to rescan: Failed to parse /home/user/.local/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop file: cannot process file of type application/x-desktop

Edit 1:
I realized one more thing. That error in the syslog appears only when I open the .desktop file, edit and save it (with nano). I guess, system checks if the file is edited (via inotify maybe?) and tries to scan it.

Edit 2:
As @Terrance suggested, I tried to login with different desktop environments. I had the following available:

1. GNOME
2. GNOME Flashback (Compiz)
3. GNOME Flashback (Metacity)
4. GNOME on Xorg
5. Ubuntu (this was default)
6. Ubuntu on Wayland
7. Unity

Except for Unity and GNOME (1 and 7) I got the syslog error after editing the .desktop file. None of them showed the desktop action.

Comment: Have you logged into Wayland or XOrg?  You might need to login into XOrg.

Comment: You upgraded from 16.04 to... 18.04 I assume? It comes with newer gnome-terminal, and as such, newer corresponding .desktop file. The command line parameters you use are no longer all available. I recommend that you start over with the current official desktop file of gnome-terminal, and apply your modifications one by one, checking at every step if it still works or not. (This question sounds like one which probably you yourself could answer the most easily by bisecting between the working and the non-working versions, rather than anyone else spotting the issue.)

Comment: @egmont I tried that. I simplified to find out what is wrong. It seems to be more complicated than that. I reinstalled the gnome-terminal to recreate .desktop file at /usr/share... Then I copied over to .local/share... Then I tried to add one more action as simple as possible. This gave my error already. I can't figure out what is wrong with it?! There is no documentation on the error either.

Comment: What desktop environment are you logged into?  Log out, click the cogwheel next to your name and see if XOrg is one of the options.  The error is saying that it can't load `x-desktop` which is not found in Wayland.

Comment: @Terrance I edited the answer

Comment: Log in with the GNOME on Xorg and try it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out with the help of @Terrance and @egmont.
It turns out to be that there are two Terminal .desktop entries:

1. gnome-terminal.desktop (old probably remaining from 16.04)
2. org.gnome.Terminal.desktop (new probably came with 18.04)

When I was searching for Terminal in "Activities" I was able to see two Terminal applications, one of which had the custom desktop action. Not the one on my dock. I found this question:
[Ubuntu 18.04, standard Ubuntu Dock, multiple action syntax in .desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032723/ubuntu-18-04-standard-ubuntu-dock-multiple-action-syntax-in-desktop-file)
An answer there mentions this double entry.
I renamed my file to the new name and it now has all the custom desktop entries. The syslog error is very misleading and I still don't get what it means. Maybe, the name doesn't correspond to any package? I don't know.